# Hash value of three doubles

Tags: swift, hash, set, double

Have object holds three values of doubles. Two objects are equal if all three values are equal in any possible combination. Need a function to determine number of "unique" objects in array.
I think about make Set from array and return count, but conforming to Hashable protocol requires hashValue function...
Coding on Swift but algorithm on any language (except alien) would be appreciated :)

So I need hashValue of three doubles (order of values doesn't matter) or any other solution of determining number unique objects in array

**UPDATE:** "Unique" means not equal. As I said above equal of two objects with double values (a, b, c for example) is equal of all three values in any possible combinations. For example:

```
obj1 = (a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)
obj2 = (a: 3, b: 2, c: 1)
// obj1 is equal obj2
```

Comment: `Need a function to determine number of "unique" objects in array` please explain this, i am quite wonder that what kind of uniqueness you are trying to find in objects in fact they can be from same class or diff.

Comment: Is there a typo in your example? Why is 1,2,3 equal to 3,1,1? Perhaps you meant for obj2 to be 3,1,2 or 3,2,1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of making a class holding 3 Doubles `Hashable` so that you can use `Set` to determine how many unique ones are held in an array:

```
class Triple: Hashable {
    var a: Double
    var b: Double
    var c: Double

    // hashValue need only be the same for "equal" instances of the class,
    // so the hashValue of the smallest property will suffice        
    var hashValue: Int {
        return min(a, b, c).hashValue
    }

    init(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    }
}

// Protocol Hashable includes Equatable, so implement == for type Triple:
// Compare sorted values to determine equality    
func ==(lhs: Triple, rhs: Triple) -> Bool {
    return [lhs.a, lhs.b, lhs.c].sorted() == [rhs.a, rhs.b, rhs.c].sorted()
}

let t1 = Triple(a: 3, b: 2, c: 1)
let t2 = Triple(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)
let t3 = Triple(a: 1, b: 3, c: 2)
let t4 = Triple(a: 3, b: 3, c: 2)

let arr = [t1, t2, t3, t4]

// Find out how many unique Triples are in the array:    
let set = Set(arr)
print(set.count)  // 2
```

---

**Discussion:  A better hashing function**

As @PatriciaShanahan noted in the comments, using `min` in the computation of `hashValue` has a couple of drawbacks:

1. `min` can be expensive since it involves comparisons.
2. Only considering the smallest item when computing the `hashValue` for `Triple` will result in many "common" `Triple`s with the same `hashValue`.  For instance, any `Triple` with a value of `0` and two positive values would have the same `hashValue`.

I chose `min` because I felt it was easy to understand that the `min(a, b, c)` would result in the same value for all orderings of `a`, `b`, and `c` which means we'd get the same `hashValue` for all orderings.  That is important because since we are considering `Triple`s to be equal independent of the orderings of the 3 values, the `hashValue` must be the same for any ordering of the values since `a == b` implies `a.hashValue == b.hashValue`.

I had considered other hashing functions such as:

- `(a + b + c).hashValue`
- `(a * b * c).hashValue`

but these are flawed.  Mathematically speaking, addition and multiplication are commutative, so theoretically these would result in the same `hashValue` no matter the order of `a`, `b`, and `c`.  But, in practice, changing the order of operations could result in an *overflow* or *underflow*.

Consider the following example:

```
let a = Int.max
let b = Int.min
let c = 5

let t1 = (a + b) + c  // 4
let t2 = (a + c) + b  // Overflow!
```

An ideal hashing function for class `Triple`would:

1. Guarantee the same `hashValue` for all orderings of `a`, `b`, and `c`.
2. Be fast to compute.
3. Would change the result if any of `a`, `b`, or `c` change.
4. Could not *overflow* or *underflow*.

One good mathematical operation for combining numbers is the *bitwise OR* function `^`.  It combines two values by comparing them *bitwise* and setting the resulting bit to `0` if both bits are the same and to `1` if the bits are different.

```
 a    b    result
---  ---   ------
 0    0      0
 0    1      1
 1    0      1
 1    1      0
```

Extending this to 3 values:

```
 a    b    c    result
---  ---  ---   ------
 0    0    0      0
 0    0    1      1
 0    1    0      1
 0    1    1      0
 1    0    0      1
 1    0    1      0
 1    1    0      0
 1    1    1      1
```

As shown in the table above, `XOR(0, 0, 0) = 0` for all orderings, `XOR(1, 0, 0) = 1` for all orderings, `XOR(1, 1, 0) = 0` for all orderings, and `XOR(1, 1, 1) = 1` for all orderings.  So using *exclusive OR* to combine the values meets the first criterium of providing the same result for all orderings.

*Exclusive OR* is a fast operation.  It is implemented by a single assembly instruction.  So it meets the second criterium of a good hashing function.

If any of `a`, `b`, or `c` changes, then the result of `a ^ b ^ c` would change.  So *exclusive OR* meets the third criterium of a good hashing function.

*Exclusive OR* cannot overflow or underflow because it simply sets the bits.  So it meets the fourth criterium of a good hashing function.

Thus, a better `hashing` function would be:

```
var hashValue: Int {
    return a.hashValue ^ b.hashValue ^ c.hashValue
}
```

Comment: Does Set uses isEqual not hashValue for checking unique?

Comment: Yes, Set uses `==` for determining equality.  You can verify this by putting my example into a Playground and changing `hashValue` to always return `1`.

Comment: Thanks for such wide answer, vacawama, already implemented another solution, but sure will try this for improving/testing speed

Comment: @zzheads, is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: I'm sure I did, let me check

Comment: min involves comparisons, which can be expensive, and maps a lot of common combinations to the same hash code. For example, both objects have one zero and two positives. Any reason to use min rather than xoring the doubles' hash codes or similar?

Comment: Thanks @PatriciaShanahan, I chose min because it is easier for a beginner to grasp and the min of 3 items only requires 2 comparisons so I didn't expect it to be THAT expensive. Your point is valid and I'll update my answer to add a discussion of better hashing functions since SO is for more than just the OP.